Is this windshield corner crack repairable?
Just noticed an isolated corner crack on my 14 Audi s4’s windshield. I almost can’t even notice it from the inside as it’s so high up. The question is whether this kind of a crack is repairable by a professional or maybe even a DIY repair kit? My guess is that it won’t split any further as its point to point around the edge but not sure.


Windshield cracks are not repairable. The only thing which is possibly repairable when it comes to windshields is if you get a bullseye type hit from a rock or something similar. Even with bullseye cracks, if there are any radiating cracks longer than approximately and inch in length, it wouldn't be repairable. About the only thing which might be done is to mitigate a crack by stopping it from getting any bigger. The crack in your windshield has already ran to the edge of the glass and won't spread any further. Mind you, a new crack may form from where the current crack takes the weird turn near the top of the glass.
Two things regarding the crack.

It depends on the laws where you live as to whether it will pass inspection. Some places on require that a crack not be in the line of sight, while other places will say if it is in the driver's side of the windshield it fails. Other places may be even more strict than that, so be aware of your local laws.
Here in the States, many insurance companies have a reduced deductible for glass replacement. You may want to check to see if your insurance company offers it.

